# Downloading and using different backgrounds for different menus in WPF in c#

Tags: c#, css, wpf

Ok, using WPF on my app, the background picture for my app i would like to change another background with each different menu change of

> > "menuComboBox"

currently its only on

> > "Trainer.ContentPage"
> >     , found in 
> >     ImageSource="/Trainer;component/Resources/content.jpg"

ive made provision to receive different menu option background files thru tokens, 
which  i can get access to with :

```
oS.fullUrl = $"http://Mysite-testing.net/t_server/download.php?token={selectedMenu.key}";
```

How do i download and use the downloaded background image in my app's WPF setup, and C# code wise

```
<TextBlock Text="Select Menu:" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
            <ComboBox Name="menuComboBox" Width="Auto" Margin="8,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}, ElementName=enableButton}" 
                      SelectionChanged="menuComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right..got it done, more in C#, by creating an bitmap image from the downloaded file, as the wpf section

```
private void updateBackground(MenuSelect _menu)
    {
        // Check Background
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_menu.BackGround))
        {
            // Web Client Object
            using (var objClient = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    // Download Image
                    String szUrlAddress = String.Format("http://my_site.com/t_server/download.php?token={0}", _menu.BackGround);
                    byte[] imgData = objClient.DownloadData(szUrlAddress);
                    if (imgData.Length > 0)
                    {
                        using (var objStream = new MemoryStream(imgData))
                        {
                            // Create Bitmap Image
                            var myBitmapImg = new BitmapImage();
                            myBitmapImg.BeginInit();
                            myBitmapImg.StreamSource = objStream;
                            myBitmapImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                            myBitmapImg.EndInit();
                            myBitmapImg.Freeze();

                            // Create Image
                            Image myImage = new Image();
                            myImage.Source = myBitmapImg;

                            // Create Image Brush
                            ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
                            myBrush.ImageSource = myImage.Source;

                            // Set Background
                            this.Background = myBrush;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    log("Background Exception: \"" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }

private void selectMenu(MenuSelect _menu)
        {
...
...
...
 Manager.Instance.selectMenu(_menu);
 updateBackground(_menu);

 ...
 ...
 }


<TextBlock Text="Select Menu:" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
            <ComboBox Name="menuComboBox" Width="Auto" Margin="8,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}, ElementName=enableButton}" 
                      SelectionChanged="menuComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```